SAP B1 Error: "Data Table - invalid Unique Id [66000-138]"
I am making a SAP B1 version 10 addon.
I have a form with a textbox. I have a choose from list for items in that textbox.
When I run the addon, the first time I open the form, and click on the choose from list and select and item, I am able to add data with no problem. When I close the form and open it again, and select an itemcode from the CFL, I get the error message: "Data Table - invalid Unique Id [66000-138]". What could be causing this?
See code below:
if (
    pVal.FormTypeEx == "ContinuousProduction.TapelineGoodsIssue"
    && pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_CHOOSE_FROM_LIST
    && pVal.ColUID == "Col_0"
    && pVal.BeforeAction == false
)
{
    SAPbouiCOM.IChooseFromListEvent oCFLEvento = null;
    oCFLEvento = ((SAPbouiCOM.IChooseFromListEvent)(pVal));
    string sCFL_ID = null;
    sCFL_ID = oCFLEvento.ChooseFromListUID;
    oForm = Application.SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID);

    SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromList oCFL = null;
    oCFL = oForm.ChooseFromLists.Item(sCFL_ID);

    if (oCFLEvento.BeforeAction == false)
    {
        SAPbouiCOM.DataTable oDataTable = null;
        oDataTable = oCFLEvento.SelectedObjects;

        oForm.Freeze(true);
        if (oDataTable.IsEmpty == false)
        {
            string itemCode = null;
            string itemName = null;
            string inStock = null;
            string factor = null;

            if (oDataTable.UniqueID == "CFL_Item")
            {
                itemCode = System.Convert.ToString(oDataTable.GetValue(0, 0), null);

                oRecordSet.DoQuery(
                    "SELECT T0.\"ItemName\", T0.\"IWeight1\" FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.\"ItemCode\" = '"
                        + itemCode
                        + "'"
                );
                oRecordSet.MoveFirst();

                if (oRecordSet.RecordCount > 0)
                {
                    itemName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item("ItemName").Value.ToString();
                    factor = oRecordSet.Fields.Item("IWeight1").Value.ToString();
                }

                oRecordSet.DoQuery(
                    "SELECT T0.\"OnHand\" FROM OITW T0 WHERE T0.\"ItemCode\" = '"
                        + itemCode
                        + "' AND T0.\"WhsCode\" = '"
                        + ComboBox1.Value
                        + "'"
                );
                oRecordSet.MoveFirst();

                if (oRecordSet.RecordCount > 0)
                    inStock = oRecordSet.Fields.Item("OnHand").Value.ToString();

                (
                    (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)Matrix0.Columns.Item("Col_0").Cells.Item(pVal.Row).Specific
                ).Value = itemCode;
                (
                    (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)Matrix0.Columns.Item("Col_1").Cells.Item(pVal.Row).Specific
                ).Value = itemName;
                (
                    (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)Matrix0.Columns.Item("Col_2").Cells.Item(pVal.Row).Specific
                ).Value = inStock;
                (
                    (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)Matrix0.Columns.Item("Col_4").Cells.Item(pVal.Row).Specific
                ).Value = ComboBox1.Value;
                (
                    (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)Matrix0.Columns.Item("Col_5").Cells.Item(pVal.Row).Specific
                ).Value = factor;
                //oDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            }
        }
        oForm.Freeze(false);
    }
}

Error is thrown here:
itemCode = System.Convert.ToString(oDataTable.GetValue(0, 0), null);

